# How to make a random not deplicate with another random number VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make the content of a button be a random number each time the user opens the application. Here is the code so far.

```
 Dim rndnumber As Random
    Dim number1 As Integer
    Dim number2 As Integer
    Dim number3 As Integer
    Dim number4 As Integer
    Dim number5 As Integer
    Dim number6 As Integer
    Dim number7 As Integer
    Dim number8 As Integer
    Dim number9 As Integer
    Dim number10 As Integer
    Dim number11 As Integer
    Dim number12 As Integer
    Dim number13 As Integer
    Dim number14 As Integer
    Dim number15 As Integer
    Dim number16 As Integer
    Dim number17 As Integer
    rndnumber = New Random

    Do
        number1 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number2 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number3 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number4 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number5 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number6 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number7 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number8 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number9 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number10 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number11 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number12 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number13 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number14 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number15 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number16 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
        number17 = rndnumber.Next(0, 18)
    Loop Until number1 IsNot number2 Or number3 Or number4 Or number5 Or number6 Or number7 Or number8 Or number9 Or number10 Or number11 Or number12 Or number13 Or number14 Or number15 Or number16 Or number17

    button1.Content = number1.ToString
    button2.Content = number2.ToString
    button3.Content = number3.ToString
    button4.Content = number4.ToString
    button5.Content = number5.ToString
    button6.Content = number6.ToString
    button7.Content = number7.ToString
    button8.Content = number8.ToString
    button9.Content = number9.ToString
    button10.Content = number10.ToString
    button11.Content = number11.ToString
    button12.Content = number12.ToString
    button13.Content = number13.ToString
    button14.Content = number14.ToString
    button15.Content = number15.ToString
    button16.Content = number16.ToString
    button17.Content = number17.ToString
```

Here is the first of 17 buttons, i have the same code for each button but have chanaged the "loop until number1 isnot number 2" part to match each different number.

The problem is at the "Isnot" part at the loop.

How can i get it to understand the value of each rndnumber?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working with this current approach? Also, is it just you want random numbers or is it that you also don't want duplicated random numbers?

Comment: Google "vb.net random shuffle" for hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add each random number to a list, then in the `Loop While` condition add something like: `rndList.Count <> rndList.Distinct.ToList.Count`.

Here's a quick 1 AM go at it:

```
Dim rndnumber As Random = New Random
Dim rndList As List(Of Integer)

Do
    rndList = New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 1 To 17
        rndList.Add(rndnumber.Next(0, 18))
    Next
Loop While rndList.Count <> rndList.Distinct.ToList.Count

button1.Content = rndList(0).ToString
button2.Content = rndList(1).ToString
button3.Content = rndList(2).ToString
button4.Content = rndList(3).ToString
button5.Content = rndList(4).ToString
button6.Content = rndList(5).ToString
button7.Content = rndList(6).ToString
button8.Content = rndList(7).ToString
button9.Content = rndList(8).ToString
button10.Content = rndList(9).ToString
button11.Content = rndList(10).ToString
button12.Content = rndList(11).ToString
button13.Content = rndList(12).ToString
button14.Content = rndList(13).ToString
button15.Content = rndList(14).ToString
button16.Content = rndList(15).ToString
button17.Content = rndList(16).ToString
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it appears to be working, i changed RndList.Add(rndnumber.next(1,18) so it wouldnt show the number 0, now to study this code and see why it works, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, and if this satisfies your question, please mark as answer so that the question is closed.  As far as "why it works" goes, it's simple: we're filling a list each time we loop with 17 random numbers.  Then we're relying upon two list properties, .count and .distinct.  Distinct will return a new set which removes all non-unique values, so that we're left with the "distinct" values.  If the count of the original list and the count of the "distinct" list are the same, then your original list has no duplicates!  The loop will end, and the code will continue execution.

Comment: Thanks again mate, and thanks for the information as to why it works, your blood is worth bottling as we say in Australia.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I don't use windows-phone, so this answer is mostly relative to .Net in general and may be not applicable as-is*

To work that way your code would have to have a giant condition with something like that (with variables shortened):

```
Loop While n1 <> n2 AndAlso n1 <> n3 ... AndAlso n1 <> n17 AndAlso n2 <> n3 ... AndAlso n16 <> n17
```

That's 16 + 15 + ... + 1 = 136 condition to write and fullfill ; There is a great chance you'll be stuck for a while in that loop.

A simpler approach is to construct an array with your values and then shuffle it; something like :

```
' suppose a Random instance named "rnd" created somewhere
Dim values = Enumerable.Range(0, 18).OrderBy(Function(unused) rnd.NextDouble).ToArray

button1.Content = values(0).ToString
' same for other button
```

Maybe it should also be possible to have some kind of loop to fill the values inside the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes that your buttons are named as shown.  It is a .Net Forms approach but might be modified to work with Phone.

```
    Dim rndnumber As New Random
    Dim butContent As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(1, 17).ToList

    For x As Integer = 1 To 17
        Dim idx As Integer = rndnumber.Next(butContent.Count)
        Dim cntnt As String = butContent(idx).ToString
        butContent.RemoveAt(idx)
        Me.Controls("button" & x.ToString).Text = cntnt
    Next
```